# Android- Log in to a website and get HTML code

Tags: java, android, html

I am extremely new to Android, and can't seem to find a way to do this. I want to **log in to Facebook** after retrieving the user's credentials, and **then get the HTML from the webpage**. I would greatly appreciate if anyone has an answer and can explain it clearly and in a simple way.

Thanks.

edit: I did some googling, and I think I have to use something called HTTPS POST Request...does anyone know how to use this or if I am wrong in believing that this must be used?

Comment: You need to use Facebook SDK to login to Facebook

Comment: Ok, but I want to login to other websites as well...facebook was just an example of one of the websites i want to log in to. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Then you have to use their SDKs and read their documentations to figure out how to integrate their code into your app.

Comment: Certain websites dont have sdks available...I was hoping for some code that could be used for every website

Comment: If you one a stop shop solution, you really need to use a third party library that helps do that. There is no way to write 1 piece of code yourself that would allow you to login to other social media apps as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks, do you know any third party libraries that could do this? To clarify, one of the websites I want to log in to is my school website, which of course does not have an SDK

Comment: You could search Google for it, for your school website, I think you could ask the people who wrote the website to see if they could help you integrate their app into yours. They don't have the SDK of course because it is not meant for everyone to use

Comment: I did Google it; however I could not find the libraries. I will try contacting my school.

Comment: If you can't find it, maybe no one has started such a project, then you really just have to work your way through

Comment: OK, thank you so much. I believe I have to use HTTPS post request, but I'm not sure what it is. I will research it and post a solution if it works